# jQuery intellisense not working fully mvc on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I have an MVC 5 application built off the Web application template.  It is referencing jQuery 3.1.1 and the template uses the Bundler to reference everything from the shared layout page.

Just now starting to get into using jquery for some AJAX postbacks for filtering searching, etc.  I see several examples across the web with

```
$.ajax....
```

notation, but my intellisense does not list this as a valid item.  All I see valid after `$.` are `apply`, `arguments`, `attr`, `attrHooks`, etc.

I have tried the method with changing tools->options->javascript->intellisense to point to the local `_references.js` (which has the correct files referenced), but I still don’t get anything that the jQuery API lists as valid methods.

Answer (score 2):

Remove jquery-ui-1.12.1.js and jquery-ui-1.12.1.js from _references.js and it should work again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by downgrading jquery to version 2.2.4 via NPM.  Still no answer as to why, but this at least allows intellisense to function.